# Meteor Spacebars - {{#each}} params

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

This is my code:

***HTML***

Card 1:

```
<!-- Shopping list -->
<div id='shopping' class='card'>
  {{#each task}}
  <ul class="card__task">
    <li>{{taskText}}</li>
    <i class="fa fa-minus delete-task"></i>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Card 2:

```
<!-- Medicine list -->
<div id='medicine' class='card'>
  {{#each task}}
  <ul class="card__task">
    <li>{{taskText}}</li>
    <i class="fa fa-minus delete-task"></i>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

***template.helper***

```
  task: function() {
    return Tasks.find({}, {
      sort: {
        createdAt: -1
      }
    });
  }
```

***tasks collection example***

*Ex.1:*

```
   ...
  "taskGroup": "medicine",
  "taskText": "medicine task 1",
   ...
```

*Ex.2:*

```
   ...
  "taskGroup": "shopping",
  "taskText": "shopping task 1",
   ...
```

So, I got a collection where I store tasks with the `taskGroup` corresponding to the `textarea input id`. For now `each` iterates over every task that I have in my `tasks collection` and those 2 cards show all tasks.

**Question:**

How can tell `each` block to only iterate over tasks that have `taskGroup` equal to this cards `id`?

Something like:

```
  task: function() {
    return Tasks.find({
    taskGroup: *the card where each block is located*.getAttribute("id");
    }, {
      sort: {
        createdAt: -1
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a blaze helper that does the filter by the taskGroup

```
tasks: function(taskGroup) {
return Tasks.find({
taskGroup: taskGroup;
}, {
  sort: {
    createdAt: -1
  }
});
```

}

That way you can call it on the template like this

```
{{#each tasks 'medicine'}}
...
{{/each}}
```